# What's the right word, he/him?

Tags: pronouns

We know that it was he.
Is this sentence correct? Or should I swap 'he' by 'him'?

Comment: [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpronouns%5D+he+him) are some posts that might help you.

Comment: Prescriptivists say nominative "he", but everyone else says accusative "him"!

Answer (score 0):

"He" is correct under the classical rules of English grammar, but in modern, colloquial American English, "him" is the only choice that would not sound odd.